# Trying to fully understand a small batch-file of a project I took over from it's previous Programmers

Tags: php

Okay, so I've taken over this project and I need help understanding a batch-file while also rewriting it a little. The batch-file contains only these three lines:

```
@echo off
start php/php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t drawtool
start "" http://127.0.0.1
```

I understand the first line, which basically hides the command prompt from view.
I might not fully understand the last line, but I'm guessing that it starts up my default browser and opens up the localhost-address.

The second line however, I have no idea what -S or -t are. Usually I would just google this, but I've really tried for hours. I simply can not find anything out about these dash-commands followed by letters.

Another thing about the second line I do not understand is why the word 'drawtool' is written at the end.

I'll try to elaborate the project's directory tree that the batch-file interacts with. It starts out with a folder named InputTool. The InputTool contains a few subdirectories, which I'll explain below:

```
InputTool (parent folder #1)
    DrawTool (folder)
        index.php

    php (folder)
        php.exe (executable file, I'll get back on this)
        additional ddl- & configuration-files

    start.bat (this is the batch file that I have trouble understanding)
```

What I want to do is to move the php folder & the batch file outside of their parent folder (one level up). So that they're now in the same directory as the InputTool folder. And I'd want the batch file to still work properly after that, while also understanding what -S, -t & how the structure of the second line works.

Comment: You can type `php.exe -h` at a cmd prompt to get help on what those switches mean.  http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: My Google Foo must be stronger.  I don't ever use PHP and all I did was Google search and it was the third link Google found.

Comment: I kept thinking -S & -t were Batch commands instead of PHP commands, since I was writing in a batch-file. So all of my searches included the word 'batch'. I knew it had something to do with misinformation, but it was hard to determine what it was up until you linked me to a php website. Thanks!

Comment: Any command line arguments that come after an executable are always arguments for that executable.  If you would have looked at the HELP file for the `START` command you could have seen that `-S` and `-t` are not options for the `START` command. Not too mention the `START` command uses a `/` for its arguments.  So all things being equal they were the arguments for `PHP.exe`.  Occam's Razor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@echo off`

Yes, as you guessed this hides the commands from the command prompt.

```
start php/php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t drawtool
```

This line starts PHP which is the executable `php.exe` in folder `php`. It will launch a PHP web server on localhost port 80 (option `-S`).
Based on the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/fr/features.commandline.options.php), option `-t` specifies the document root for built-in web server. So it will execute scripts (aka index.php) inside this folder (drawtool).

```
start "" http://127.0.0.1
```

And finally, yes this opens your default navigator to the address of the server.

So basically, to answer your second question, as all paths here are relative, the batch file should still work as long as `php.exe` stays at the same place relative to `start.bat`, or if you edit the paths correctly.

Comment: I've changed nothing, I've only moved the batch-file & php-folder one level up and now it won't work anymore. Either the PHP server won't start, or the webpage won't load, or both (the symptoms are inconsistent). But if i move them back into the parent folder, everything will work fine again.

Comment: You have to move the `drawtool` folder one level up too or change the path to the document root in the command.
So if I understood correctly it would give : `start php/php.exe -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t InputTool\drawtool` or something similar